# Как отправлять множество запросов sql в рамках одного соединения?

Tags: mysql, sql

в основном потоке подключился к пользователю mysql, в дочерних потоках пытаюсь отправлять запросы mysql, но вылезает ошибка

`Error: Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

или

`Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

Нужно чтобы в рамках одного соединения я мог отправлять большое количество запросов одновременно без всяких ошибок,как это сделать?

Comment: Не могли бы вы дополнить вопрос ссылкой на документацию, где сказано, что такое возможно. И добавте пожалуйста ваш код.

Comment: @0xdb, возможно ли такое?  А код я и так описал, суть в том что одновременно посылаются запросы серверу mysql с одного соединения

Comment: Ну это я вас просил добавить, где написано, что это возможно. Раз вы тоже не находите, то нет, это невозможно - одно соединение может обрабатывать только один запрос в определённый промежуток времени.

Comment: @0xdb, печально

Comment: Да, mysql не может обрабатывать более одного запроса на соединении. Так что вам в приложении надо делать пулл соединений к БД или фиксированно создавать по соединению под поток

Comment: @Mike, да уже понял, сразу что-то затупил, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Это невозможно, МySQL не может обрабатывать более одного запроса на одном соединении, так что нет никого смысла работать в разных потоках с одним соединением.

В приложении надо в каждом потоке создавать новое соединение к БД.